# Count type objects in a list

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x, instances

Have you a great method to count number of `Sugar` in my `goblet`?

```
class Sugar:pass
class Milk:pass
class Coffee:pass

goblet = [Sugar(), Sugar(), Milk(), Coffee()]
sugar_dosage = goblet.count(Sugar) #Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
sum(isinstance(x, Sugar) for x in goblet)
# or
sum(1 for x in goblet if isinstance(x, Sugar))
```

Also, `list.count` did not work because the method was testing how many items in the list *equaled* `Sugar`.  In other words, it was basically doing `item==Sugar` for each item in the list.  This is incorrect because you want to be testing the *type* of each item, which is what `isinstance` does.